# Custom validation, on two lines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Is there a way to validate an input field using just a few lines of code?

Right not I've to do this when using a custom validation.

**Model**

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
end
```

**Validator**

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email") unless
      value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
    end
  end
end
```

This is what I really want to do.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :email => lambda  do |record, value|
    record.errors[:email] << "invalid field" unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  end
end
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm just going to put this here... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Comment: Also, the validation should be on your model, not your controller.

Comment: @Beerlington To much copy and paste, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :my_custom_validator

  def my_custom_validator
    if @email.to_s.match(/hello/)
      self.errors[:email] << "Email can't contain the word 'hello'"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ActiveModel's validates_format_of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_format_of

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
end
```

Or use the shortcut:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create }
end
```

Comment: Using regexp was just an example.